# Dart/Flutter : convert BigInt to json

Tags: json, flutter, dart, serialization, bigint

I have an object with a bigint property i want to encode to json string:

```
class Token {
  Token(
      {
      this.name,
      this.supply,
      });

  String? name;
  BigInt? supply;

  factory Token.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Token(
      name: json['name'],
      supply: json['supply'] == null ? null : BigInt.parse(json['supply']),
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => <String, dynamic>{
     'name': name,
     'supply': supply == null ? null : supply!.toString(),
  };
}
```

I create a method to encode json to string...

```
String tokenToJson(Token data) => jsonEncode(data.toJson())
```

... but the format is not correct because i need a bigint in the format json and not a string:

the result i want:
`{"name":"Token","supply":100000000000000,}`

the result i obtain:
`{"name":"Token","supply":"100000000000000",}`

jsonEncode doesn't manage bigint type and i found on internet only solutions with a conversion of the bigint to a string type.

NB: Same issue with `jsonDecode`

Thx

Comment: If you need to use a `BigInt`, that means that you need to store arbitrarily large integers exactly.  You therefore *must* write it as a `String` in JSON if you want to guarantee a lossless round-trip.  Writing it as a numerical value can work only if the number is representable as a IEEE-754 double-precision floating-point number, but if that's the case, you could have used `double` instead of `BigInt` in the first place.

Comment: Can I just ask where your requirement of `BigInt` comes from? The reason I ask is that I have seen multiple people here thinking they need `BigInt` because they are using a SQL database where a field are of the type `bigint`. But if you then read the documentation you can see that `bigint` in e.g. PostgresSQL actually means a 64 bit signed integer which are a normal `int` in Dart.

Comment: you're right. i use int instead of BigInt and that's ok. Thank you all for help

Comment: @julemand101 1. A Dart `int` is a 64-bit signed integer *for the Dart VM* (i.e., not when transpiled to JavaScript). 2. If the full 64-bit width is required, then since JSON is based around JavaScript, you can't rely on storing 64-bit `int`s either if the JSON is meant to be portable.  It's probably fine if both endpoints are running in the Dart VM though.

Comment: @jamesdlin I keep forgetting about the existing of JavaScript... You are absolutely correct.

Answer (score 1):

use this simple method instead of BigInt use just "num"

```
        import 'dart:convert';
                void main() {
                String data = '''{"name":"Token","supply":100000000000000}''';
                print("supply: ${Token.fromJson(jsonDecode(data)).supply}");
                }
        
        
        class Token {
            Token({
                required this.name,
                        required this.supply,
            });
            late final String name;
            late final num supply;
          
          Token.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
                name = json['name'];
                supply = json['supply'];
            }
        
            Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
                final _data = <String, dynamic>{};
                _data['name'] = name;
                _data['supply'] = supply;
                return _data;
            }
        }
```

Comment: This correct way to convert and digit to number.

Comment: Thanks @KumarLokeshRathod it will helpful to others

Comment: This answer doesn't use `BigInt` at all, although if the OP *really* wants the output they describe, they can't use `BigInt`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to parse, you can use from for convert int to `BigInt`

```
import 'dart:convert';
void main() {
  String data = '''{"name":"Token","supply":100000000000000}''';
  print(Token.fromJson(jsonDecode(data)).toJson());
}


class Token {
  String? name;
  double? supply;

  Token({this.name, this.supply});

  Token.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    name = json['name'];
    supply = json['supply'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['name'] = name;
    data['supply'] = supply;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Comment: ok. thank you. But what about toJson method to obtain: "supply": 1000000 instead of "supply": "1000000" ?

Comment: check out the updated answer

Comment: This is misleading since it prints a `Map`, and converting a `Map` to a `String` will not print quotes around `String` keys or values.  It would still output `supply: "100000000000000"` when encoded to a JSON string.  Fundamentally `BigInt`s *must* be encoded as `String`s, so either OP needs to accept that or must accept not using `BigInt`s.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following answer, instead of calling toString method on supply just call toInt method which will prevents the quotations and you will get the formatted json as expected

```
import 'dart:convert';

class Token {
  Token(
      {
      this.name,
      this.supply,
      });

  String? name;
  BigInt? supply;

  factory Token.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Token(
      name: json['name'],
      supply: json['supply'] == null ? null :BigInt.from(json['supply']) ,
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => <String, dynamic>{
     'name': name,
     'supply': supply == null ? null : supply!.toInt(),
  };
  
    String tokenToJson(Token data) => json.encode(data.toJson());
}

void main() {
  
  Token token = Token(name: "token_one",supply : BigInt.parse("10000061234567"));
  print(token.tokenToJson(token));

}
```

Output

```
{"name":"token_one","supply":10000061234567}
```

Comment: As I noted in a comment, this sort of approach would work only if the `BigInt` happens to be representable as a `double`.  This wouldn't work if you used, say `BigInt.parse("10000000123456789")`.